# Is Pumping lemma so useful? (Michael Sipser "Introduction to the Theory of Computation 3rd Edition")

Tags: soft-question, automata, regular-language

I am reading "Introduction to the Theory of Computation 3rd Edition" by Michael Sipser.

Pumping lemma is the following proposition:

> **THEOREM 1.70**
> **Pumping lemma** If $A$ is a regular language, then there is a number $p$ (the pumping length) where if $s$ is any string in $A$ of length at least $p$, then $s$ may be devided into three pieces, $s=xyz$, satisfying the following conditions:
>
> 1. for each $i\geq 0$, $xy^iz\in A,$
> 2. $|y|>0$, and
> 3. $|xy|\leq p.$

In this book, when the author prove some language is not regular, he always uses Pumping lemma.

For example, the author uses Pumping lemma to prove the following $C$ is not regular.

> EXAMPLE 1.74
> Let $C=\{w\mid w\text{ has an equal number of }0\text{s and }1\text{s}\}.$ We use the pumping lemma to prove that $C$ is not regular. $\cdots$

The author's proof of EXAMPLE 1.74:

> Assume to the contrary that $C$ is regular. Let $p$ be the pumping length given by the pumping lemma. As in Example 1.73, let $s$ be the string $0^p1^p$. With $s$ being a member of $C$ and having length more than $p$, the pumping lemma guarantees that $s$ can be split into three pieces, $s=xyz$, where for any $i\geq 0$ the string $xy^iz$ is in $C$. We would like to show that this outcome is impossible. But wait, it *is* possible! If we let $x$ and $z$ be the empty string and $y$ be the string $0^p1^p$, then $xy^iz$ always has an equal number of $0$s and $1$s and hence is in $C$. So it *seems* that $s$ can be pumped.
> Here condition 3 in the pumping lemma is useful. It stipulates that when pumping $s$, it must be divided so that $|xy|\leq p$. That restriction on the way that $s$ may be divided makes it easier to show that the string $s=0^p1^p$ we selected cannot be pumped. If $|xy|\leq p$, then $y$ must consist only of $0$s, so $xyyz\notin C.$ Therefore, $s$ cannot be pumped. That gives us the desired contradiction.
> Selecting the string $s$ in this example required more care than in Example 1.73. If we had chosen $s=(01)^p$ instead, we would have run into trouble because we need a string that *cannot* be pumped and that string *can* be pumped, even taking condition 3 into account. Can you see how to pump it? One way to do so sets $x=\epsilon,y=01,$ and $z=(01)^{p-1}.$ Then $xy^iz\in C$ for every value of $i$. If you fail on your attempt to find a string that cannot be pumped, don't despair. Try another one!

I think we can easily prove that $C$ is not regular even if we don't know what the pumping lemma is.
I think it is important to notice we can use the idea of pigeonhole principle.
His approach seems too prescriptive.

Is the pumping lemma really useful?
Is there a problem which is very difficult if we don't know the statement of the pumping lemma?

I suspect that pumping lemma is a proposition not worth naming.

---

My idea is the following picture (the same idea as pumping lemma):
[image]

Let $M$ be a DFA which recognizes $C$.
Give a sufficiently long string $00000000$ to $M$.
$M$ must contain a submachine like the above picture because the set of the states of $M$ is finite and $00000000$ is sufficiently long and $0000000011111111\in C$.
Then, $0000000000000011111111\in C$ must holds.
But this string has fourteen $0$s and eight $1$s.

Comment: I know nothing of the subject. But generally if you have a powerful theorem at your disposal, allowing for a quick and almost thoughtless argument (because you really know this theorem) people will want to use it

Comment: @FShrike Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: What is your proof?

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I wrote my idea.

Comment: That is exactly the proof of the pumping lemma, albeit only for this one specific language, but the general proof is the same. Cool!

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I wanted to say that I suspect that pumping lemma is a proposition that does not deserve a name.

Comment: Think about like this. Suppose that, instead of a lemma which you can apply (by verifying its hypotheses are true, and therefore its conclusion is true), every time that you would have liked to apply that lemma, you are instead forced to repeat the proof of that lemma. Then a lot of mathematics papers would be longer in a way that is not particularly helpful or illuminating. Someone would come along and say *You're all taking up pages to repeat the same argument over and over. Why don't you just write a lemma, write its proof once, and then we can all apply the lemma and write better papers?*

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: When I took a course from Sipser, I remember thinking the same thing as you in the regular language chapter, but finding the context-free pumping lemma -- which is introduced a chapter later -- to be much more useful. I recommend understanding the regular language pumping lemma even if it feels like overkill, because then the context-free pumping lemma will be easier to grasp.

Comment: @Micah Thank you very much for your advice.